# PHP and MYSQL:how to automatically generate new tables from existing table

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I’m an estimator, not a programmer. I've been using Excel on estimating purpose for many years. On each file, there are multiple tabs for each type of material price by diameter and by thickness. Each tab looks like this but much bigger:

```
Material A

Size     1" thick    2" thick   3" thick   4" thick    5" thick
____
2”              
4”              
6”              
8”              
10”
```

Then I have a data input tab to decide the discount rate for each type of material. Then I have a takeoff tab for entering the materials required and quantities information and looking up the price from each respective tab. The takeoff could be over 10,000 rows. By doing this, I have an excel file for each project. When it comes to a big project, we have multiple guys doing takeoff, and I have to merge their file to mine.

A couple years ago, I used PHPrunner 8.1 and mysql to build a system for work safety and training records. Now I’m considering the same tool to design an online takeoff system so that multiple colleagues can collaborate on one job and I don’t have to do copy and paste anymore. I start with a project_input table and each row is for the project specific data. And I build standard price tables for each type of material.

Then my problem is that it seems I have to create separate sets of price tables to reflect discounted rates for each project. I just wonder how I could automatically generate a set of price tables when I enter a new project into the project_input table. Any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: A simple SQL script adding prices? Or you could have a table to specify discounts for the current project. We don't have your database model to give a specific answer.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).